# How to recover from java.lang.ClassNotFoundException after project clean in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I just did a project...clean and then automatically nothing works.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: adventure/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: adventure.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: adventure.Main. Program will exit.
```

I can do build but in eclipse there is no output for build and they thought that it is some advantage that you can't just right-click a file and select compile...

Why did they make Eclipse able to go into this unmanageable state? What is the advantage with this state? If there is no advantage with this state of the project, why is it possible?

I did nothing unusual except experimenting with my build path to be able to generate a runnable JAr which of course failed since eclipse can't even package a jar correctly.

The code from the class won't help showing here since it is not found anyway.

### Update

I can reproduce this error just by doing a "fresh" SVN checkout and then work on the project and as soon as I use the "function" clean then eclipse automatically destroys my work and makes it impossible to continue the project just because I'm using Eclipse  the world's luosiest IDE ever that they had a *decade* to developer and this can't get to do basic function like compile.

Comment: what precisely is the question here?

Comment: "How to resolve this Eclipse java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

Comment: Can you show us some code? or give us some more information about the project. This most likely isn't an Eclipse issue.

Comment: if the issue is a ClassNotFoundException, then obviously the solution is to help it find the class... but since we don't know anything else about your project/context, there's not a whole lot else to say. As @Recursed says, it's probably not a bug in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must agree with the comments that it is unlikely this issue was caused by Eclipse. Never the less, assuming it was:

Eclipse works this way because it uses an autobuilder rather than compile after the fact. This can be nice as far as error-catching, but can also be problematic for large projects. As to why a simple manual compile isn't provided, Eclipse is attempting to hide such development steps as compilation and likely didn't consider the cases where such errors could occur.

Try turning the autobuild function off and back on again:
Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Build automatically

If that doesn't work:
Make a backup of the file containing the class and then delete it. Restore from the backup.

Either of these should force Eclipse to recompile everything.

If that still doesn't solve your problem, then the error probably wasn't from Eclipse, it just never had a chance to find it after whatever cleaning you did. Thankfully, by forcing Eclipse to recompile, it should point you at the error.

Comment: I did nothing unusual, just experimenting with my build path from the IDE. I used only controls in the IDE and could get my project in this state. This proves that Eclipse allows unmangeable states.

Comment: Dude, everybody is being a little too kind. You already have your mind made up that Eclipse sucks because it allows you to make a class path that doesn't let your project compile. That's nonsense. Any tool that lets you override automated classpath generation will allow you to break your build.

Comment: @KevinWelker Thank you for the comment. Don't you agree that my error appears completely random and unrelated to my programming and is nothing but a strange eclipse configuration?

Comment: Perhaps unrelated to your Java code, but not unrelated to your configuration, which is a significant part of programming.  I'm sorry it's not working and I hope you find the problem. It just seems your attitude is "my tool stinks and I did nothing wrong", and I think that attitude won't help you grasp whatever the cause of the problem is.  I wish you the best results.

Comment: You mentioned in the question comments that you messed with the build path. If you did this manually, you'll need to refresh the project or clean won't work properly.

As for you doing nothing wrong, you've done something erroneous in your usage of Eclipse. Get the idea of right vs wrong out of your head and debugging will become a lot easier. It is always better to assume the error is on oneself until the root cause is understood. This doesn't mean you are in the wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it isn't "ideal" , but in such Problem,
in Eclipse me halps : Project clean, and and build automatically